# Grouping and Transforming in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My data have the following structure:

```
       Name     Value       id
0    Alegro  0.850122   alegro
1    Alegro  0.447362   alegro
2    AlEgro  0.711295   alegro
3    ALEGRO  0.123761   alegro
4    alegRo  0.273111   alegro
5    ALEGRO  0.564893   alegro
6    ALEGRO  0.276369   alegro
7    ALEGRO  0.526434   alegro
8    ALEGRO  0.924014   alegro
9    ALEGrO  0.629207   alegro
10  Belagio  0.834231  belagio
11  BElagio  0.788357  belagio
12  Belagio  0.092156  belagio
13  BeLaGio  0.810275  belagio
```

To replicate run the code below:

```
data = {'Name': ['Alegro', 'Alegro', 'AlEgro', 'ALEGRO', 'alegRo', 'ALEGRO','ALEGRO',
                 'ALEGRO','ALEGRO','ALEGrO', 'Belagio','BElagio', 'Belagio', 'BeLaGio'],
     'Value': np.random.random(14)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['id'] = df.Name.str.lower()
```

You can see that there are some typos im dataset.

```
df.groupby('id').Name.value_counts()

id       Name   
alegro   ALEGRO     5
         Alegro     2
         ALEGrO     1
         AlEgro     1
         alegRo     1
belagio  Belagio    2
         BElagio    1
         BeLaGio    1
```

So the aim is to take the most frequent value from each category and set it as New name. For the first group it would be `ALEGRO` and for second `Belagio`.

The desired data frame should be:

```
       Name     Value       id
0    ALEGRO  0.850122   alegro
1    ALEGRO  0.447362   alegro
2    ALEGRO  0.711295   alegro
3    ALEGRO  0.123761   alegro
4    ALEGRO  0.273111   alegro
5    ALEGRO  0.564893   alegro
6    ALEGRO  0.276369   alegro
7    ALEGRO  0.526434   alegro
8    ALEGRO  0.924014   alegro
9    ALEGRO  0.629207   alegro
10  Belagio  0.834231  belagio
11  Belagio  0.788357  belagio
12  Belagio  0.092156  belagio
13  Belagio  0.810275  belagio
```

Any idea would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame`, so possible create new column.

```
df['New'] = df.groupby('id').Name.transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
```

Another solution:

```
df['New'] = df.groupby('id').Name.transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
```

---

```
print (df)
       Name     Value       id      New
0    Alegro  0.850122   alegro   ALEGRO
1    Alegro  0.447362   alegro   ALEGRO
2    AlEgro  0.711295   alegro   ALEGRO
3    ALEGRO  0.123761   alegro   ALEGRO
4    alegRo  0.273111   alegro   ALEGRO
5    ALEGRO  0.564893   alegro   ALEGRO
6    ALEGRO  0.276369   alegro   ALEGRO
7    ALEGRO  0.526434   alegro   ALEGRO
8    ALEGRO  0.924014   alegro   ALEGRO
9    ALEGrO  0.629207   alegro   ALEGRO
10  Belagio  0.834231  belagio  Belagio
11  BElagio  0.788357  belagio  Belagio
12  Belagio  0.092156  belagio  Belagio
13  BeLaGio  0.810275  belagio  Belagio
```